# Looping JSON data jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, encode

I am trying to find how to loop through JSON with the "fields" array. You can see the JSON data has "fields":["fullname","email"]} how do I loop this with jquery? You can see it's hard coded right now:

```
rows = rows + '<td>'+value.fullname+'</td>';
rows = rows + '<td>'+value.email+'</td>';
```

I am looking to do something like:

```
        $.each( data.fields, function( key, value ) {
          rows = rows + '<td>'+value.key+'</td>';
        });
```

JSON Data

```
{"data":[{"fullname":"Test User","email":"testuser@gmail.com"},{"fullname":"Karim Ali","email":"karimali831@googlemail.com"}],"total":2,"fields":["fullname","email"]}
```

Table loop

```
function manageRow(data) {
    var rows = '';

    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

        /*
        $.each( data.fields, function( key, value ) {
          alert( key + ": " + value );
        });
        */

        rows = rows + '<tr>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.fullname+'</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.email+'</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td data-id="'+value.id+'">';
        rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-primary edit-item">Edit</button> ';
        rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
        rows = rows + '</td>';
        rows = rows + '</tr>';
    });

    $("tbody").html(rows);
}
```

PHP fetch

```
    public function getUsers()
    {               

        $num_rec_per_page = 5;

        if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };

        $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page;

        $fields = array("fullname", "email");


        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $req = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT " . implode(", ", $fields) . " FROM users Order By id desc LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page");
        $req->execute();
        $data['data'] = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //$data['total'] = $req->fetchColumn();
        $data['total'] = 2; // Total rows from table

        $data['fields'] = $fields;

        return json_encode($data);      

    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: P.s. doing `rows = []; rows.push('string content');rows.push('string content'); $('tbody').html(rows.join(''))` might be a bit faster and easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over `data.data` and `data.fields`

```
var rows = "";
$.each(data.data, function(_, element) {
    rows = rows + '<tr>';
    $.each(data.fields, function(__,key) {
        rows = rows + '<td>' + element[key] + '</td>';
    });
    rows = rows + '<td data-id="'+value.id+'">';
    rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-primary edit-item">Edit</button> ';
    rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
    rows = rows + '</td>';
    rows = rows + '</tr>';    
});
```

Comment: thanks but I tried this and it didn't return any data.

Comment: You tried with this parameters ? Copy/paste this instead of your loop and try as-is, do a `console.log` on `rows` and check what's inside, then I'll try to see what can be done

Answer (score 0):

I had figured it out:

```
function manageRow(data) {
    var rows = '';

    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        rows = rows + '<tr>';

        $.each(data[1], function( key2, value2 ) {
            rows = rows + '<td>'+value[key2]+'</td>';
        });

        rows = rows + '<td data-id="'+value.id+'">';
        rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-primary edit-item">Edit</button> ';
        rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
        rows = rows + '</td>';
        rows = rows + '</tr>';
    });

    $("tbody").html(rows);
}
```